# Map and filter in scheme

Tags: dictionary, filter, scheme, mit-scheme

I'm trying to return a list with all the strings removed

```
(remove-strings '(("hello" 9) (29 10) ("cruel" "world") (1238 .12) (-53 "end"))))
=> ((9) (29 10) () (1238 .12) (-53))
```

here's the code i've got so far
    (define (remove-strings list)
     (filter string? list))

I'm also trying to square all negative numbers in the list so 'ive got

```
(define (neg-sqr list)
  (map square (filter negative? list)) ; filters out negatives in list and squares each number
)
```

should return
    2809 because it takes the square of each negative number (-53^2)

however, the code above is not working. I think it's because I need to use the code from step one to remove the strings so i can get the numbers alone, or is because the items are nested one level deep? Could anyone help me with the remove-strings procedure?

Comment: what's your current implementation of `remove-strings`? first, post the code as part of the question

Comment: also, post an example detailing the expected output of `neg-sqr`, as you did for the first part of the question

Answer (score 1):

Using an accumulate function like this:

```
(define (accumulate op initial sequence)
  (if (null? sequence)
      initial
      (op (car sequence)
          (accumulate op initial (cdr sequence)))))
```

It is a simple matter of making the call to accumulate correctly.

```
(define (remove-strings n)
   (accumulate (lambda (x y) (cons (filter number? x) y)) () n)
  )
```

What this does is repeatedly apply the procedure lambda to each sub-list and then cons's them together leaving you with your string-less new list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for taking the negative number out

```
(define (f2b items)
   (accumulate (lambda (x y)
 (cons (append 
    (map square (filter negative? (filter number? x))
)
(filter positive? (filter number? x))
(filter string? x)
) y)) () items))
```

ps. did you figure out the sum of all positive numbers one?

Answer (score 0):

`filter` takes a list as an argument.
However, your input to `remove-strings` is a list of lists, and you want to process them individually.
Perhaps you could figure out a way to apply a function to each item in a list?